# Jquery how to get html value of id (nearest id / id in the same row)

Tags: jquery

With php foreach get html like below. So `id` is like price1, price2, price3 etc.

User may change quantity. In such case i must multiply price with changed quantity. I decided to do it with jquery.

At first access to `quantity`.

```
$( '[id^="quantity"]' ).change(function(){
var quantity = $(this).val();
});
```

But can not get html value of price. Tried

```
var price = $(this).find( '[id^="price"]' ).attr('id');
var price = $(this).find( 'div[id^="price"]' ).html();
```

In both cases got `undefined`

Here is part of html code

```
<div class="shop_cart_box_around">

   <div class="shop_cart_price">
     <div class="span_cart_name_txt" id="price1">789</div>
   </div>

   <div class="shop_cart_quantity">
     <input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity1" value="3"/>
   </div>

</div>

<div class="shop_cart_box_around">

   <div class="shop_cart_price">
     <div class="span_cart_name_txt" id="price2">54</div>
   </div>

   <div class="shop_cart_quantity">
     <input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity2" value="1"/>
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the parent element which has class **shop_cart_box_around** using `closest()` and then use `find()` to get its child element like this:

```
$(this).closest(".shop_cart_box_around").find( '[id^="price"]' ).attr('id');
```

For getting price (means price div value) use `text()`:

```
$(this).closest(".shop_cart_box_around").find( '[id^="price"]' ).text();
```

```js
$(function(){

  $( '[id^="quantity"]' ).change(function(){
var quantity = $(this).val();
  alert("Id : "+ $(this).closest(".shop_cart_box_around").find( '[id^="price"]' ).attr('id'));
 alert("Value : " +$(this).closest(".shop_cart_box_around").find( '[id^="price"]' ).text());
});

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shop_cart_box_around">

   <div class="shop_cart_price">
     <div class="span_cart_name_txt" id="price1">789</div>
   </div>

   <div class="shop_cart_quantity">
     <input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity1" value="3"/>
   </div>

</div>

<div class="shop_cart_box_around">

   <div class="shop_cart_price">
     <div class="span_cart_name_txt" id="price2">54</div>
   </div>

   <div class="shop_cart_quantity">
     <input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity2" value="1"/>
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That should get the ID of the price div but it won't get the price.

Comment: var price = $(this).closest(".shop_cart_box_around").find( '[id^="price"]' ).html(); This works. Thanks!

Comment: Use `val()` not `html()` for input elements

Comment: price is not input. Only quantity is input